# Android AsyncTask fails

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been doing some testing on the class listed below, it works great except...

When i do the button click and they try to switch fragments it crashes. Line 752: `getActivity().getContentResolver().update(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHARTING, values, null, new String[] {StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE,cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE)) + ""});` however i don't know why its failing.

```
public class ChartingFragment extends Fragment implements OnDateSetListener, OnClickListener {
    ...

public class WebPageAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String userID = null;

        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","Fetching User");
        //Get the user
        Cursor cursorUser = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER, null, null, null, null);

        cursorUser.moveToFirst();

        if (cursorUser.getCount()>0 && cursorUser!=null) {
            // Record found
            if (cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_ID)) == null) {
                Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","KEY_USER_ID is null, need to upload the user information");
                //this user has logged in with facebook but has not be synced before.
                //Push user information to my online database.

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> httpParams;

                httpParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();                        
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fbid", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_ROWID))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("social", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_SOCIAL))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_NAME))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_FNAME))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_USERNAME))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_EMAIL))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_PICTURE))));
                httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("other", cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_OTHER))));

                try {
                    SERVICE_URL = new URL("http://www.projectcaruso.com/android/com.projectcaruso/naturalfamilyplaning/postUser.php");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "MalformedURLException: " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String response= "";

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) SERVICE_URL.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(getQuery(httpParams));
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();

                    conn.connect();

                    //start listening to the stream
                    Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

                    //process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
                    while(inStream.hasNextLine())
                    response+=(inStream.nextLine());

                    Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","response: " + response);

                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Error: " + e.toString());
                }

                 catch (IOException e) {
                     Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", e.toString());
                }


                // First split the input String into an array,
                // each element containing a String to be parse as an int
                String[] intsToParse = response.split("\"");

                int[] info = new int[intsToParse.length];
                int _id = 0;

                // Now just parse each part in turn
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                {

                    if (isNumeric(intsToParse[i].toString())) {
                        _id = Integer.parseInt(intsToParse[i]);
                    }
                }

                if (_id > 0) {
                    Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Found id: " + _id);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(StatusData.KEY_USER_ID, _id);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().update(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER, values, " 1 = 1 ", null);


                    Cursor cursorUser2 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER, null, null, null, null);

                    cursorUser2.moveToFirst();

                    userID = cursorUser2.getString(cursorUser2.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_ID));
                }

            } else {
                while (cursorUser.isAfterLast() == false) 
                {
                    //this User is already set up to send/receive charting updates 
                    Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","User found and has been connected before");
                    userID = cursorUser.getString(cursorUser.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_USER_ID));

                    cursorUser.moveToNext();
                } 
            }
        } else {
            //This user has not been set up to send/receive charting updates
            Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","User profile not set up, please login via facebook");
            Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "userID: " + userID);
            return null;
        }


        if (userID != null) {
            // Get the data
            Cursor cursorCharting = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHARTING, null, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PROC + " is null " , null, null);

            cursorCharting.moveToFirst();

            if (cursorCharting.getCount()>0 && cursorCharting!=null) {
                Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","Que'd Charting Information Found");
                while (cursorCharting.isAfterLast() == false) 
                {

                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> httpParams;

                    httpParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();                        
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PERIOD, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PERIOD))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_INTERCORSE, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_INTERCORSE))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_CERVIX, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_CERVIX))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_MOOD, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_MOOD))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_HEADACHE, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_HEADACHE))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEST, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEST))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_ENERGY, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_ENERGY))));
                    httpParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_NOTES, cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_NOTES))));

                    try {
                        SERVICE_URL = new URL("http://www.projectcaruso.com/android/com.projectcaruso/naturalfamilyplaning/postCharting.php");
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "MalformedURLException: " + e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                    String response= "";

                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) SERVICE_URL.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);

                        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                        writer.write(getQuery(httpParams));
                        writer.close();
                        os.close();

                        conn.connect();

                        //start listening to the stream
                        Scanner inStream = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());

                        //process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
                        while(inStream.hasNextLine())
                        response+=(inStream.nextLine());

                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","response: " + response);

                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Error: " + e.toString());
                    }

                     catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", e.toString());
                    }


                    // First split the input String into an array,
                    // each element containing a String to be parse as an int
                    String[] intsToParse = response.split("\"");

                    int[] info = new int[intsToParse.length];
                    int _id = 0;

                    // Now just parse each part in turn
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    {

                        if (isNumeric(intsToParse[i].toString())) {
                            _id = Integer.parseInt(intsToParse[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    if (_id >= 0) {
                        Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Insert Successful: " + _id);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PROC, "Y");
                        getActivity().getContentResolver().update(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHARTING, values, null, new String[] {StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE,cursorCharting.getString(cursorCharting.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE)) + ""});
                    }

                    cursorCharting.moveToNext();
                } 
            } else {
                Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO","No que'd Charting Information Found");
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (pair.getValue() == null) {
            Log.i("PROJECTCARUSO", "Null value pair for: " + pair.getName());
        } else {

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
                }
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  {  
          try  
          {  
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
          }  
          catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
          {  
            return false;  
          }  
          return true;  
        }
}
```

Log Cat:

```
08-01 14:43:16.801: I/PROJECTCARUSO(23019): response: {"posts":[{"auto_increment_id":"0"}]}
08-01 14:43:16.801: I/PROJECTCARUSO(23019): Insert Successful: 0
08-01 14:43:16.811: W/dalvikvm(23019): threadid=18: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f89360)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  3 arguments were provided but the statement needs 1 arguments.
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:68)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1563)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.StatusProvider.update(StatusProvider.java:81)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:992)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.ChartingFragment$WebPageAsync.doInBackground(ChartingFragment.java:752)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.ChartingFragment$WebPageAsync.doInBackground(ChartingFragment.java:1)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-01 14:43:16.831: E/AndroidRuntime(23019):    ... 5 more
08-01 14:43:24.378: D/SensorManager(23019): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*a-b:((
```

Comment: What's at line 81 of `StatusProvider`? That's where your problem is.

Comment: `count = db.update(StatusData.DATABASE_CHARTING_TABLE, values, selection, selectionArgs);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around it.... So it works but if i leave the fragment it crashes... So i tied a progress bar to it which keeps the user from leaving while its sending it to my online database. Problem may not be solved but its worked around.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open database ...!!

Just add following code before you entered query for getting data

```
Database_Object.getWritableDatabase();
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help, but no thats not it. The ContentProvider handles all database transactions, including the `Database_Object.getWritableDatabase();`. This is all about the AsyncTask, it is successful if you don't leave the fragment, if you leave the fragment it crashes.